# Stuck with responsive and timeline design with masonry

Tags: css, responsive-design, tumblr, jquery-masonry, timeline

I am very new to tumblr and jQuery Masonry, I have create a test blog.

I have a timeline design, by which posts are aligned in two sides and also I used Masonry to remove the space between the posts.
And I have added responsive behavior to this.

Post and Masonry is working properly with responsive on different window size when the page loads but when i resize the window, its design goes to haywire.

I am not able to identify is it my code's mistake or Masonry's :(
Any help will be really helpful.

[image: See this image for clear understanding]

It is not working with only `(min-width: 768px)`, `(min-width: 1024px)` and `(min-width: 1824px)`

Here is my code:
JS

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    if ($(window).width() <= 679) {
        $('#posts_container').masonry('destroy');
    }

    if ($(window).width() > 680) {
        $('#posts_container').masonry({itemSelector: '.shadow', });
    }

    Arrow_Points();
});

function Arrow_Points() {
    //alert("function call");
    var s = $('#posts_container').find('.shadow');
    $.each(s, function(i, obj) {
        var posLeft = $(obj).css("left");
        $(obj).addClass('borderclass');
        if (posLeft == "0px") {
            html = "<span class='rightCorner'></span>";
            html += "<div class='rightpostcorner'></div>";
            $(obj).prepend(html);

            $(this).addClass('margin_hack_left_post');
        }
        else
        {
            html = "<span class='leftCorner'></span>";
            html += "<div class='leftpostcorner'></div>";
            $(obj).prepend(html);

            $(this).addClass('margin_hack_right_post');
        }

    });
}
```

Media

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
.wrapper {width: 100%;}
.rightCorner, .leftCorner{ display: none; }
.shadow {width: 90%; margin: 40px 5% 10px 5%; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) and (min-width: 480px){
.wrapper {width: 100%;}
.rightCorner, .leftCorner{ display: none; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 680px){
.wrapper {width: 100%;}
.rightCorner, .leftCorner{ display: none; }
.shadow {width: 90%; margin:  40px 5% 10px 5%; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .leftCorner { margin-left:-9%;}
    .shadow { width: 45.5%; margin-top: 40px; }
    .margin_hack_left_post { margin-left:1.5%%; }
    .margin_hack_right_post { margin-left:7.5%; }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1824px) {
.wrapper {width: 100%; }
.leftCorner {margin-left: -5.5%; }
.shadow { width: 43.7%; margin-top: 40px; }
.margin_hack_left_post { margin-left:4%; }
.margin_hack_right_post { margin-left:8%; }
}

/* LARGE SCREENS */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1824px) {
.wrapper {width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;}
.shadow { width: 43.7%; margin-top: 40px; }
.margin_hack_left_post { margin-left:4%; }
.margin_hack_right_post { margin-left:8%; }
}
```

My CSS:

```
   .shadow
    {
        float: left;
        background-color: #ffffff;
        min-height: 50px;
        text-align: justify;
        word-wrap:break-word;
    }

    .timeline_container
    {
        width: 16px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 auto;
        cursor:pointer;
        display: block;
    }

    .timeline
    {
        margin: 0 auto;
        background-color: red;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 100%;
        left: 49.75%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 1px;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    .timeline:hover{cursor: pointer;margin: 0 auto;}

    .timeline div.plus{width: 14px;height: 14px;position: relative;left: -6px;}

    .rightCorner
    {
        background-image: url("xyz.png");
        height: 30px;
        margin-left: 99.5%;
        margin-top: 8px;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 30px;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .leftCorner
    {
        background-image: url("abc.png");
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        margin-top: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        z-index:2;
    }

    .content
    {
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        max-width: none;
        min-width: 86%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
    }
```

And my tumblr HTML is

```
      {block:Posts}
        <article class="shadow">
            {block:Date}
            <div class="post_info">
                <section class="post-controls">
                    <ul style="padding-left: 0px; float: left; width:80%">
                        <li style="width: 30%; margin-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 7px;">
                            <i class="icon-clock"></i> {DayOfMonthWithZero} {ShortMonth} {ShortYear}
                        </li>
                        {block:NoteCount}<li style="width: 30%; margin-left: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin-top: 7px;">
                            <i class="icon-heart"></i> {NoteCount}</li>{/block:NoteCount}
                    </ul>

                    <ul style="float:right;">
                        <li class="like_link">{ReblogButton size="20"}</li>
                        <li class="reblog_link">{LikeButton size="20"}</li>
                    </ul>
                </section>
            </div>
            {/block:Date}

            <div class="post_padding">
                {block:Audio}
                <div class="audio" id="{PostID}">
                    <div class="album_art">{block:AlbumArt}<img class="scale-with-grid" src="{AlbumArtURL}" />{/block:AlbumArt}</div>
                    <div class="audio_player_container">
                        {block:AudioEmbed}{AudioEmbed}{/block:AudioEmbed}
                        {block:AudioPlayer}{AudioPlayerWhite}{/block:AudioPlayer}
                    </div>

                    <div class="caption">
                        <ul class="audio_details">
                            {block:TrackName}<li><span class="audio_bold">Song Title:</span> {TrackName}</li>{/block:TrackName}
                            {block:Artist}<li><span class="audio_bold">Artist:</span> {Artist}</li>{/block:Artist}
                            {block:Album}<li><span class="audio_bold">Album:</span> {Album}</li>{/block:Album}
                            <li><span class="audio_bold">Plays:</span> {PlayCount}</li>
                        </ul>

                        {block:Caption}{caption}{/block:Caption}
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/block:Audio}

                {block:Chat}
                {block:Title}<div class="chat_title"><h2><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h2></div>{/block:Title}
                {block:Lines}
                <div class="lines"><div class="line {Alt}">{block:Label}<strong>{Label}</strong>{/block:Label} {Line}</div></div>
                {/block:Lines}
                {/block:Chat}

                {block:Link}
                <div class="link_title"><a href="{URL}" {Target}>{Name} &rarr;</a></div>
                <div class="caption">{block:Description}{Description}{/block:Description}</div>
                {/block:Link}

                {block:Photo}
                <div class="photo_post">
                    <a href="{Permalink}" rel="prettyPhoto">
                        <img class="scale-with-grid" src="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
                {/block:Photo}

                {block:Photoset}
                <div class="photo-slideshow" data-layout="{PhotosetLayout}">

                    {block:Photos}
                    <div class="photo-data">
                        <div class="photo">
                            <a href="{Permalink}" rel="prettyPhoto[set]">
                                <img alt="{PhotoAlt}" src="{PhotoURL-500}" data-highres="{PhotoURL-HighRes}" class="{block:Exif}exif-yes {/block:Exif}{block:Caption}caption-yes{/block:Caption}" {block:Exif}data-camera="{block:Camera}{Camera}{/block:Camera}" data-iso="{block:ISO}{ISO}{/block:ISO}" data-aperture="{block:Aperture}{Aperture}{/block:Aperture}" data-exposure="{block:Exposure}{Exposure}{/block:Exposure}" data-focal="{block:FocalLength}{FocalLength}{/block:FocalLength}"{/block:Exif} {block:Caption}data-caption="{Caption}"{/block:Caption}>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="icons">
                            <a rel="prettyPhoto" class="view" rel="post-{PostID}" href="{PhotoURL-HighRes}"><span class="zoom">Zoom</span></a>
                            <span class="info">Info</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {/block:Photos}
                </div><!-- close SLIDESHOW -->

                <div class="caption">{block:Caption}{Caption}{/block:Caption}</div>
                {/block:Photoset}

                {block:Quote}
                <div class="quote_title"><h2>"{Quote}"</h2></div>
                <div class="caption"><p>{block:Source}- {Source}{/block:Source}</p></div>
                {/block:Quote}

                {block:Text}
                {block:Title}<div class="post_title"><h2><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></h2></div>{/block:Title}
                <div class="caption">{Body}</div>
                {/block:Text}

                {block:Video}
                <div class="video_post">
                    <figure><div class="embed">{Video-500}</div></figure>
                    {block:Caption}<div class="caption">{Caption}</div>{/block:Caption}
                </div>
                {/block:Video}
            </div>
        </article>
        {/block:Posts}
```

Comment: Can you provide a URL to your blog maybe?

Comment: Ok. http://aj-theme1.tumblr.com/

Comment: Try to set 'left:50%;' instead of hard-pixels for the right boxes..

Comment: Can you specify where should I put this and try? in which class?

Comment: The left margin for the right-posts, get generated due to window size.

Comment: It is working. please post this as answer. I will mark accepted :)

Comment: What exactly have you done? Did you change the hard-pixels to 50% for the left margin?

Comment: that hard pixels were given by masonry, so I put left: 50% to right posts in javascript which overwrites masonry's left. inside that arrow function in else block, I added $(this).css("left", "50%");

Comment: Awesome! Great job, I will put it up as answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javascript will generate hard-pixels for the left-margin, depending on the width of browser window. Change the hard pixels to 50%.

**jQuery:**

```
$(this).css("left", "50%");
```